# How to exclude chars and ints in the same for loop?

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure this out for hours with no avail. Basically I need to print out user input as Initial value, ASCII(char), ASCII(int), and Hex. I can get everything to work however I am not supposed to have the char values print if its a digit, and int values print if its a char. I can get everything to work except I cannot figure out how to exclude both the letters and digit in the same for loop. The way it has to be printed is quite strict. My code below will print the Initial, ASCII(char) and Hex values. I have another if statement that will work by itself to print the ASCII(int) - but obviously if I include that if statement it will exclude everything.. Any help would be Amazing thank you..

"What the output is supposed to look like"
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slrjq.jpg]

```
import java.util.*;

/****************************************************************************************
HNUnit3Ch12.java
xx

Write a program that gets input for a string, then output the initial character, ascii 
values of the character and number, and hex values of each character. Repeat until quit.
Get input for a string containing both numbers and letters of any length
Use a for loop with postfix notation to increment through the string, printing the
following:
The initial digit/character
The ASCII value of each character
The ASCII value of each integer converted to a string
Only output the ASCII(char) for letters and ASCII(int) for integers
Spaces should output ASCII(char) and hex only
The Hex value of each integer/character output in upper case
Output “Thank you for playing!”
****************************************************************************************/

public class HNUnit3Ch12
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String HEADER = "%-10s%-15s%-15s%s";
        //final String OUTPUT = "%s\n %-15s\n %-15s\n %s";
        String userString;

        System.out.print("Please enter a string of any length: ");
        userString = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(HEADER, "\nInitial", "ASCII(char)", "ASCII(int)", "Hex\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i ++)
        {
            char ch = userString.charAt(i);

            char initialCase = userString.charAt(i);

            if (!Character.isDigit(ch))
                {
                int letters = (int) ch;

            //if (!Character.isLetter(ch))
            //  {
            //  int numbers = (int) ch;

            String hex = Integer.toString(ch, 16).toUpperCase();

            System.out.printf("%-9s%-9s%-9s%n",initialCase,letters,hex);
                }
            //  }
        }

    } // End main
} // End public class HNUnit3Ch12
```

Comment: You should have two different printfs, one for digits and one for non digits

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

- The example output has columns that are 8, 16, and 16 wide. Your [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) formats should reflect that.
- Since the second `printf` uses `%n`, you already know how that works, so why is the first `printf` not using it?

  ```
  System.out.printf("%n%-8s%-16s%-16s%s%n", "Initial", "ASCII(char)", "ASCII(int)", "Hex");
  ```
- To print a number in decimal, use `%d`, and to print a number in hex, use `%x`. To always print hex as 2 digits, use `%02x`.

  ```
  // for char
  System.out.printf("%-24s%-16d%02x%n", ch, (int)ch, (int)ch);

  // for int
  System.out.printf("%-8s%-32d%02x%n", ch, (int)ch, (int)ch);
  ```

Since `printf` does all the work for you, you code is simple:

```
System.out.printf("%n%-8s%-16s%-16s%s%n", "Initial", "ASCII(char)", "ASCII(int)", "Hex");
for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i ++) {
    char ch = userString.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        System.out.printf("%-24s%-16d%02x%n", ch, (int)ch, (int)ch);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%-8s%-32d%02x%n", ch, (int)ch, (int)ch);
    }
}
```